# WHERE OR Query - CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-futon, nosql

How would I do a "where or" query in couchDB? I am used to SQL and would normally do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City='Berlin'
OR City='München';
```

I have a basic view in futon that looks like:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.city) {
    emit(doc.city, doc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it have an `IN` operator, like `WHERE City IN ('Berlin', 'Munchen')`?

Comment: The above SQL was just an example! But yes the IN operator is another good example. If I can do this in CouchDB or the jQuery couch library that be great!

Answer (score 2):

With a simple view index like this (ie: does not emit an array as it's key) you can query a view for multiple keys very easily. Instead of using a `GET` request, use a `POST` and send a body like:

```
{
  "keys": [
    "Berlin",
    "München"
  ]
}
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#post--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view) for more details.

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of the view code please?